# Cannot delete Directory on Android rooted device

Tags: android, root, delete-file

I have a strange issue, I cannot access/delete or do anythid to Download directory on my sdcard.
Here's what i got from adb shell:

```
root@hammerhead:/mnt/shell/emulated/0 # ls -l                                
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2014-11-22 12:17 0
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2014-11-20 16:16 ABF
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          1970-11-25 00:25 Alarms
drwxrwx--x root     sdcard_r          2014-11-13 16:40 Android
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2014-11-24 12:08 Bing
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2014-11-13 22:55 DCIM
lstat './Download' failed: Permission denied
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2014-11-22 09:23 ExtractedApks
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2014-11-13 18:08 HyprmxShared
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          1970-11-25 00:25 Movies
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          1970-11-25 00:25 Music
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2014-12-01 14:41 Nikon_WU
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2014-11-13 18:06 Notifications
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2014-11-26 11:34 Pictures
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          1970-11-25 00:25 Podcasts
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          1970-11-25 00:25 Ringtones
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2014-12-06 20:26 SmartVoiceRecorder
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2014-12-05 16:38 TitaniumBackup
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2014-11-25 00:18 UnityAdsVideoCache
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2014-11-15 09:53 WhatsApp
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2014-12-05 15:32 airdroid
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2014-11-13 19:10 amazonmp3
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2014-11-17 00:13 aquery
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2014-11-14 17:33 clockworkmod
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2014-11-16 12:45 com.facebook.orca
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2014-11-13 16:47 data
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          1970-11-24 22:28 legacy
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2014-11-13 18:03 media
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          1970-11-24 22:24 obb
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2014-12-05 15:56 ppy_cross
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2014-11-13 17:55 romtoolbox
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2014-12-05 15:32 storage
drwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r          2014-11-15 05:58 stt-dump
root@hammerhead:/mnt/shell/emulated/0 # rm -R Download/                        
rm: Download: Permission denied
1|root@hammerhead:/mnt/shell/emulated/0 # lsattr -a Download                   
lsattr: stat Download: Permission denied
root@hammerhead:/mnt/shell/emulated/0 # chattr -i Download                     
chattr: stat Download: Permission denied
root@hammerhead:/mnt/shell/emulated/0 #
```

I've also tried using a terminal emulator on the device, but I got the same errors, I cannot see or delete the directory.
The problem is that I cannot download anything on my device since the Download dir is not accessible.

Comment: do you have this permission in your manifest file? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: try adb root or make sure that you do not enable "Protect Sd card" in Settings->Developer options.

Comment: Which Android version are you using? You might have messed up SELinux contexts. This might be fixable by using [`restorecon`](http://blog.wadegarrett.com/blog/2014/08/10/easy-solution-for-sdcard-error-on-android-l).